# SqlServer Database replication in remote datacenter. Which kind of replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

Disclaimer: I am a developer, not a DBA.

**Scenario**

Currently two servers (Web Edition) in a private cloud in one single datacenter in Europe.
1 DB per client + 1 common DB used by all clients.

We are extending to North America. We need to host NA customers in a NA datacenter.

Requirement: Replicate the common DB to the NA datacenter.
The size of the DB is currently 3-4GB. The bulk of the load is in a time series table, growing at around 15000 rows a day (~2MB) (+ other modifications in other tables, less volume).

What replication scenario would you recommend ?
I don't need immediate replication/mirroring. There can be some delay, although not too long (e.g. 1 minute seems reasonable (rule of thumb). If options include longer delay, this can be discussed). Allowing extra subscriber nodes would be nice to have.

From what I read on the Web, I believe snapshot replication is not a good idea for replication across long distances. Transactional and peer-to-peer replication look interesting. What would work best for me?

TIA

Comment: Do you need one read/write and one read-only, or are you looking for read/write on both ends?

Comment: Web Edition has some relatively restrictive feature limitations. Would it be possible to upgrade to Standard Edition? Or must answers work with Web Edition?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if you need to replicate data from Europe (SQL Server 2016 Web Edition) to America, lets see what options we have:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2016

Below features do NOT fit for you:

- Database Mirroring (in Web Edition SQL Server can be only in Witness role, it can not be a primary or secondary)
- Availability Groups / Failover Cluster Instances (mostly Enterprise / Standard Edition level features)
- Transactional / Snapshot Replication  (in Web Edition SQL Server can be only in Subscriber role, can't be a Publisher or Distributor)

You are left only with Log Shipping option, it works in Web Edition
Log Shipping has configurable delay between log backups on primary and log restores on secondary

Comment: Log shipping won't meet OP's ballpark of 1 minute goal for latency. Additionally, it requires making the database unavailable when performing restore operations.